# Atributo dir, html ou css

Tags: html, css

O atributo `dir` geralmente é omitido para idiomas *LTR* (default) e usado para *RTL* - que são escritos da direita para a esquerda (arábico e afins), com a finalidade de mudar a direção, mas não encontrei nada relevante além disso.

Usar o *PHP* para encontrar a *direction*, pode usar como base o idioma do navegador e ficheiros para carregar as configurações. Se usar o *CSS* para alterá-la, precisaria apenas combinar uma class com o mesmo nome do idioma, e isso acabaria aliviando um monte de processo.

```
// css
.en_US, .pt_BR{direction:ltr}
.eg{direction:rtl}

// html
<body lang="pt_BR" class="pt_BR">
```

**Pergunta**

Podemos omitir e manter a direção usando apenas o CSS (`direction:rtl`), ou o atributo *dir* tem alguma outra aplicação?

Já testei leitores de tela, mas na época não me atentei a isso. Eles identificam a direção do texto pelo atributo, ou são pré-configurados?

Comment: oo leitor de tela não precisa desse atributo, pois no source as coisas são sempre no mesmo sentido. O que o atributo faz é inverter a direção ao exibir apenas (o que é melhor, pois o texto original funciona sempre igual, conforme digitado)

Comment: Dúvida inocente: o atributo `dir` vai dentro da tag `<body>`? Nunca tinha visto, `eg` é código de onde, Egito?

Comment: @brasofilo, O Attr `dir` pode ir no `body` para aplicar em todo doc, inclusive outros elementos são suportados. EG é do egito sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pergunta 1:**

> Já testei leitores de tela, mas na época não me atentei a isso. Eles identificam a direção do texto pelo atributo, ou são pré-configurados?

Nem um, nem outro. Eles não lêem baseados na direção, e sim na ordem em que os textos aparecem no código fonte HTML (do início ao fim). [[Ver referência]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404556/in-which-direction-does-a-screenreader-read-dir-rtl)

**Pergunta 2:**

> Podemos omitir e manter a direção usando apenas o CSS (direction:rtl), ou o atributo dir tem alguma outra aplicação?

Têm a mesma aplicação, segundo especificação do W3C.
Porém, **use de preferência o atributo `dir`**, segundo [recomendação do W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup.pt.php):

> Como a direção é parte integrante da estrutura do documento, deve-se usar uma marcação para determinar a direção de um documento ou trecho de informação, ou para identificar pontos no texto em que o algoritmo bidirecional não basta para alcançar a direção desejada.
> [..]
>   Entretanto , o estilo aplicado pelo CSS não é permanente. Pode ser desabilitado, ignorado, não ser reconhecido, ou alterado/substituído em diferentes contextos.
>   
> [..]
>   Procure não conectar simplesmente o estilo CSS ao elemento geral para conseguir o efeito.
> [..]
>   **HTML ou XHTML apresentado como text/html**
>   Usar somente marcação. As recomendações CSS2 indicam o uso de marcação para textos bidi em HTML. Pode-se na realidade dizer que agentes usuários de conformação do HTML podem ignorar as propriedades do bidi CSS. Pois a especificação HTML define claramente o comportamento esperado dos agentes usuários em relação à marcação bidi.

**Observação:**

Vale lembrar que a especificação Unicode já atribui uma direção aos caracteres e define o Algoritmo de Bidirecionalidade (BIDI) para a determinação da direção do texto mais apropriada.

No entanto, precisas-se que o atributo `dir` seja usado no HTML. Além disso, o W3C especifica que o `dir` não deve se inferido a partir do idioma (`lang`).

**HTML 4.01:**

Se você estiver usando a versão uma versão pré-HTML 5, você terá que especificar os valores `LTR` ou `RTL` para o atributo `dir`.

*([Ver especificação 8.2 do HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2)).*

**HTML 5:**

A partir do HTML 5, pode ser usado também o valor `auto`. A direção será definida de acordo com primeiro caractere "fortemente tipado", isto é, pertencente a um alfabeto - aspas, vírgulas, números, e afins não contam.

Dado a baixa complexidade desse algoritmo (ao contrário do BIDI), **somente** use esse valor quando a direção não é previamente conhecida, como conteúdos dinâmicos internacionalizados. Um `h1` contendo um conteúdo vindo do banco de dados, por exemplo. É quase certo que haverá problemas se usar nas tags `html` ou `body` - para definir a direção de um documento inteiro.

*([Ver especificação 3.2.5.6 do HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes)).*

Comment: Ótimas referências, obrigado