# É correto nomear atributos de tags html de maneira arbitrária?

Tags: html, html5, html-tags, atributos

Gostaria de saber sobre a criação e a manipulação de atributos no html que **são criados**. Nós temos os atributos já conhecidos como o *id*, *class*, etc. que colocamos nas tags para podermos manipulá-las. Fui em busca de outras alternativas de nomes, que pudessem me atender nesse fim. Vi o "*data-*" que após o mesmo pode-se colocar o nome que desejar **(me corrijam se estiver errado aqui**) e fazer tal manipulação através desse atributo que veio com o html5. Após usar o "data-", verifiquei se eu poderia criar um atributo na tag com o nome que eu desejasse. O que fiz foi o seguinte:

```
<a href="#" data-grupo="13" numberlink="1" class="link" id="um">Link 1</a>
```

Quando fui no inspecionador de elemento e selecionei o elemento através do atributo:

```
$("a[data-grupo=13]");
```

Ele encontrou o elemento. Com isso entendi que eu posso criar esses atributos de tag de acordo com o meu desejo. Porém não sei se isso é uma boa prática, pois podem existir diferenças de atributos para atributos como é o exemplo de classe e id, no qual este só pode pertencer a um elemento e aquele a mais de um elemento.

Não consegui obter resposta nessas perguntas, não encontrei o que queria aqui no so:

[Significados de atributos data-value, data-title, data-... em HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50669/significados-de-atributos-data-value-data-title-data-em-html)

[Usar os atributos unários de Tags HTML com valor atribuido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97817/usar-os-atributos-un%c3%a1rios-de-tags-html-com-valor-atribuido)

[Atributo dir, html ou css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38918/atributo-dir-html-ou-css)

Eu posso nomear atributos de tags html de acordo com a minha vontade sem isso me gerar problemas (na manipulação ou qualquer outro uso das tags ou atributos)?

Comment: Suas perguntas costumam ser exemplares.

Comment: tem algum problema delas serem assim? se tiver eu posso tentar mudar a maneira de perguntar :) Eu sempre tento testar primeiro, depois procuro aqui no so e na net, quando não acho nada que satisfaça minha dúvida eu pergunto aqui.

Comment: Tem, claro, mostra como as outras são piores :) Claro que sempre dá para melhorar, mas as suas não dá para melhorar muito, fazem tudo o que uma boa pergunta deve fazer. Parabéns!

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4829/eu-n%c3%a3o-sei-perguntar-e-voc%c3%aa?cb=1 :D

Comment: vlw bigown! obg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim e não: você não pode sair adicionado elementos imaginários como por exemplo `meunovoatributo="xxxx"` já que HTML considera válidos apenas uma série de atributo pré-definidos na especificação. Contudo `data-` foi adicionado ao HTML5 exatamente para você poder criar atributos conforme desejar, então é permitido jogar seus `data-qualquercoisa` a vontade pelo HTML.

O único problema que você poderia encontrar é colisão de um atributo `data-` seu com o de algum biblioteca externa, afinal nada impede que a biblioteca `awesomechartlib.js` que você está usando para fazer gráficos incríveis no seu app coloque `data-chart` em todas as tags, sendo que você mesmo pode estar usando esse `data-chart` com propósitos diferentes.

Quanto ao que significa um atributo ser "válido" em um tag, isso é referente a especificação do HTML. Como HTML é na verdade um subset (suconjunto) de XML a validação formal dele se dá por meio de um [DTD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Tipo_de_Documento)  (que é feito com base [nesta especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)) onde é definido o que é esta estrutura "válida". Como apontando no comentário do @Haxz isso acaba sendo uma questão de semântica correta, na prática nada te impede de adicionar atributos aleatórios incorretos e dificilmente isto te traria problemas, seu HTML provavelmente vai renderizar naturalmente em todos os browsers e usos com javascript/jQuery ou outros seletores externos de elementos, parsers HTML/XML em quaisquer linguagens por exemplo, vão funcionar como se tudo estivesse correto.

Comment: BrunoRB, o que significa ser "considerado válido"? na minha pergunta consegui recuperar o atributo criado via jquery. Nesse caso ele não seria válido?

Comment: Acho que tá mais pra um "semanticamente válido"