# Como selecionar atributos e valores no select

Tags: javascript

Como selecionar atributo (obriga) da categoria que esta setada, 
Sempre que eu clicar no botão!!

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var categorias = document.querySelector("#categorias");


btn.addEventListener("click", selecObriga);

function selecObriga(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="categorias" name="categorias">
    <option value="1" obriga="0">Cores</option>
    <option value="2" obriga="1">Animais</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btn" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `selectedIndex` (pega o `option` selecionado) e `getAttribute` (pega o atributo). Então você pode usar a variável `categorias` para pegar os valores do `select`:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var categorias = document.querySelector("#categorias");

btn.addEventListener("click", selecObriga);

function selecObriga(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var attr = categorias.options[categorias.selectedIndex].getAttribute('obriga');
  console.log(attr);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="categorias" name="categorias">
    <option value="1" obriga="0">Cores</option>
    <option value="2" obriga="1">Animais</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btn" type="submit">
</form>
```

> Quanto a usar qualquer nome como nome de atributo, talvez seja
>   interessante se inteirar a respeito do assunto **[nesta
>   pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111689/8063)**.